# Android RSS reader problems

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sqlite, rss

I have been trying to create a simple app that parse an entire channel into a string and print it and also that can save parsed data into a sqlite db in the future. I've been following [tutorial1](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser/) and [tutorial2](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/parsing-xml-from-the-net-using-the-saxparser-t353.html)
I also read the IBM tutorial together with 3-4 other implementations of RSS readers but cant figure whats wrong

Item.java

```
public class Item extends Object {
private String Data= null;
Item()  {

}
Item(String data) {
    this.Data = data;
}
public void setData(String data) {
    this.Data = data;
}
public String getData() {
    return this.Data;
}
```

}

RSSHandler.java

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {
public static final String ITEMS_TABLE="items";
private final String MY_DEBUG_TAG = "handler";
boolean inChannel = false;
public Item item;
LearDB leardb = null;
RSSHandler(Context context)
{
    leardb = new LearDB(context);
    item =new Item();
}
@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    this.item = new Item();
}  
@Override
public void endDocument( ) throws SAXException{
}  

@Override
public void startElement(String Uri, String localName, String qName, 
        Attributes atts) throws SAXException { 
    if (localName.equals("channel")) {
        this.inChannel = true;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
@Override
public void endElement(String Uri, String localName, String qName) 
throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("channel")) {
        this.inChannel = false;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
} 
@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    String temp = new String(ch, start, length);
    try {
        if (this.inChannel) {
            this.item.setData(temp);
        }
    }   catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Parsing Error", e);
    } 
}
public String getData() {
    return this.item.getData();

}
public Item getItem() {
    return this.item;
}    
public void insertItem(String temp) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = leardb.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
    value.put("data", temp);
    db.insert(ITEMS_TABLE, null, value);        
}
```

}

LearDB.java

```
public class LearDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="lear.db";
public static final String ITEMS_TABLE="items";

public LearDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);     
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = ("CREATE TABLE items (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, data TEXT);");
    db.execSQL(sql);    
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2) {
        String sql = "drop table items;";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        sql = ("CREATE TABLE items (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, data TEXT);");
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
}
```

}

main activity

```
public class test3 extends Activity {
private final String MY_DEBUG_TAG = "test2";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://achdre.freehostia.com/example.xml");// URL of XML document to be parsed
        InputSource source = new InputSource(url.openStream());
        SAXParserFactory LearParseFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser LearParser = LearParseFactory.newSAXParser(); //SAX Parser object
        XMLReader LearReader = LearParser.getXMLReader(); // Object that scans the XML document
        RSSHandler LearHandler = new RSSHandler(this); //Handler object
        LearReader.setContentHandler(LearHandler);
        LearReader.parse(source); //Parses the XML document
        String temp=LearHandler.getData();
        text.setText("12345");
        LearHandler.insertItem("android"); //inserting test string to DB
        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        text.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Parsing Error", e);
        } 
    this.setContentView(text);
}}
```

and the manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<application android:icon="..." android:label="..."android:debuggable="true">
<activity android:name=".test3"android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
android:label="@string/app_name"android:debuggable="true">
```

edit: I managed to make it run. errors were both on the xml I was trying to parse and on my handler class callback events. no need for more assistance

Comment: That's quite a lot to process. Can you verify that your activity is loading at all by perhaps adding a dummy "Hello World!" text field? Also, you could try setting a breakpoint (double-click left margin in Eclipse) early in your try block and then run the app in Debug.

Comment: I think it's loading fine because the SQLite database of the `LearHandler` object I create in my main activity is created correctly and the 3
`LearHandler.insertItem("xxxx");`
commands in main actually insert data in the database, as I can see when I retrieve it and open it
as for the breakpoint and Debug run I;ll do it in the morning and give you the answer
thanks for the help

Comment: i run the app in debug. i can tell for sure that something is happening because I am able to print text 1234 in the screen using `text.setText("1234");` 
but not when I try
`String temp=LearHandler.getData();`
`text.setText("12345");` so something is wrong with my handler class
other than that I don't really know what to find with debug run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be will help

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler 
{
    RSSFeed rssFeed;
    RSSItem rssItem;
    String lastElementName = "";
    final int RSS_TITLE = 1;
    final int RSS_LINK = 2;
    final int RSS_DESCRIPTION = 3;
    final int RSS_CATEGORY = 4;
    final int RSS_PUBDATE = 5;

    int currentstate = 0;

    public RSSHandler()
    {
    }

    public RSSFeed getFeed()
    {
        return rssFeed;
    }

    //开始解析文档
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        rssFeed = new RSSFeed();
        rssItem = new RSSItem();
    }

    //文档解析结束
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException
    {
    }

    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException
    {
        if (localName.equals("channel"))
        {
            currentstate = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (localName.equals("item"))
        {
            rssItem = new RSSItem();
            return;
        }

        if (localName.equals("title"))
        {
            currentstate = RSS_TITLE;
            return;
        }

        if (localName.equals("description"))
        {
            currentstate = RSS_DESCRIPTION;
            return;
        }

        if (localName.equals("link"))
        {
            currentstate = RSS_LINK;
            return;
        }

        if (localName.equals("category"))
        {
            currentstate = RSS_CATEGORY;
            return;
        }

        if (localName.equals("pubDate"))
        {
            currentstate = RSS_PUBDATE;
            return;
        }

        currentstate = 0;
    }

    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
    {
        //如果解析一个item节点结束，就将rssItem添加到rssFeed中。
        if (localName.equals("item"))
        {
            rssFeed.addItem(rssItem);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
    {
        String theString = new String(ch,start,length);

        switch (currentstate)
        {
            case RSS_TITLE:
                rssItem.setTitle(theString);
                currentstate = 0;
                break;

            case RSS_LINK:
                rssItem.setLink(theString);
                currentstate = 0;
                break;

            case RSS_DESCRIPTION:
                rssItem.setDescription(theString);
                currentstate = 0;
                break;

            case RSS_CATEGORY:
                rssItem.setCategory(theString);
                currentstate = 0;
                break;

            case RSS_PUBDATE:
                rssItem.setPubDate(theString);
                currentstate = 0;
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```